# CSS dimming overlay

Tags: javascript, android

I have a fullscreen (100% width and height) div that has a 60% opacity for the android browser (on a z index). On top of it, i have a form. However, everytime i try to open up the keyboard to enter any text, it seems like the keyboard is trying to push the div upwards, and it eventually just fails with the keyboard not opening up, or push the page to the very bottom. (Cyanogen mod behaviour)

On android 2.2 with HTC sense, the behaviour is similar, on top of that, the input textbox will have another instance of itself directly above the textbox.

Any idea how to avoid this type of behaviour?